# Find if a path is navigable to without navigating to it

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm looking to have my nav menu draw (or not) based on whether a route is navigable. I.e. if the router's authGuards would reject the routing it isn't rendered.

The key to this is being able to ask the router if a route could be activated.

Assuming I have a routes.ts file like this:

```
export const routes = [

    {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'tactics', component: IframeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { expectedRole: 'admin' } }
        ]
    }
];
```

And authGuard may or may not permit the route "tactics" to be activated based on the expectedRole attribute

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    // expectedRole on the data property in route config
    const expectedRole = route.data.expectedRole;
    return auth.hasExpectedRole(expectedRole);
  }
}
```

How can I ask the router (or any other appropriate service) if a particular path could be navigated to without actually navigating to it. Note that the authguard isn't just a logged in vs not logged in, it uses the data attribute "expectedRole" in the routes constant and checks if the person is both logged in **and** has that permission

I want to do this to avoid duplicating the configuration of which paths need which user permissions.

I know I could get hold of the routes constant and do the processing myself but that feels like redoing what the router already does and I'd almost certainly get some corner case wrong

Comment: Try the resolver. It will tell you whether a route is usable: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard

Comment: @DiabolicWords I can see the direction that is going in and it looks useful, thanks. But it all seems to be resolvers for if an item is available rather than if a path is resolvable?

Comment: You're right here. But I reckon that this is the only way to validate a route to exist.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a custom structural directive. It can act like *ngIf, but based on AuthGuard logic.

You should extract AuthGuard logic into separate service and than inject it into your new structural directive.

```
class LoginService {
  isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
     return of(true)
  }
}

class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public loginService: LoginService) {}

  canActivate() {
    return this.loginService.isLoggedIn();
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[ifLoggedIn]',
})
export class LoggedInDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription: Subscription;
  hasView: boolean;

  constructor(
    public loginService: LoginService,
    public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.loginService.isLoggedIn()
      .subscribe(loggedIn => {
        if (loggedIn && !this.hasView) {
          this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
          this.hasView = true;
        }

        if (!loggedIn && this.hasView) {
          this.viewContainerRef.clear();
          this.hasView = false;
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: The trouble is that this isn't just a logged in vs not logged in issue, it's logged in **and** has the expectedRole specified in the routes constant (under that routes data, which the authGuard received within the ActivatedRouteSnapshot passed to canActivate. In fact they don't see the menu at all unless they are logged in. I'm happy to configure the routes differently but I want to configure it only once (I.e. not configure that route A needs permission a and the menu item A also needs permission a)

Comment: How about getting activated data directly from <router-outlet> and passing it to the directive as @Input? I've created a simple live example showcasing how you can access the data directly from <router-outlet> - [Live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbdfq5)